# Perl, IIS 7 and DCOM

Tags: perl, iis-7, dcom

I am working on a website which uses IIS 7 and tries to create a COM server on remote machine. The flow is:

IIS_7_Computer -> Perl Script 1 -> Perl Script 2 -> Win32::OLE ---DCOM---> COM object on destination machine

The account I am using is "Administrator@IIS_7_Computer". This administrator has the same password as destination machine "Administrator"

I have enabled "Windows Authentication" for site with only provider is "NTLM".

If I launch perl script 1 from command line while logged on as Administrator@IIS_7_Computer, per script 2 is launched and it successfully creates the object.

But, if I go through the web site, by logging in as Administrator@IIS_7_Computer, I keep on getting "Access is denied" message.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Comment: Verify that the web page is running that user by printing `Win32::LoginName`.  You can configure the IIS user in the Application Pools section.

Comment: @Andomar: I have printed the LoginName and while running on command line or running in web page, both times it prints "Administrator" in perl script 1 or 2.

Comment: Honestly, DCOM is totally screwed up and has been so since 1996.  You might be able to get it to work with a lot of effort.  See if you can communicate with the remote server using a better protocol like HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to enable "Basic Authentication" under IIS instead of "Windows Authentication"

Answer (score 0):

You can use PerlIS from ActiveState. It's good & much less hassle.